# How do I solve undefined reference to interactive_markers

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile the [simple_marker.cpp tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Writing%20a%20Simple%20Interactive%20Marker%20Server) with catkin_make in Hydro and I am getting an undefined reference error:

---

```
> CMakeFiles/simple_marker.dir/src/simple_marker.cpp.o: In function `main':
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x362): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::InteractiveMarkerServer(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x549): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::insert(visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker_<std::allocator<void> > const&, boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedback_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, unsigned char)'
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x567): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::applyChanges()'
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x5b7): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::~InteractiveMarkerServer()'
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x62b): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::~InteractiveMarkerServer()'
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x662): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::~InteractiveMarkerServer()'
simple_marker.cpp:(.text+0x6f7): undefined reference to `interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer::~InteractiveMarkerServer()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/taylor/src/ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/simple_marker] Error 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/simple_marker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

I think it's because of my CMakeFiles.txt:

```
> # %Tag(FULLTEXT)% cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
> project(beginner_tutorials)
> 
> ## Find catkin and any catkin packages find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs
> genmsg)
> 
> ## Declare ROS messages and services
> #add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
> #add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
> 
> ## Generate added messages and services
> #generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
> 
> ## Declare a catkin package catkin_package(
> ##  INCLUDE_DIRS include
> ##  LIBRARIES pick
> ##  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
> ##  DEPENDS system_lib )
> 
> ## Build talker and listener include_directories(include
> ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> 
> add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(talker
> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
> add_dependencies(talker
> beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
> 
> add_executable(listener
> src/listener.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(listener
> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
> add_dependencies(listener
> beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
> 
> add_executable(simple_marker
> src/simple_marker.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(simple_marker
> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
> add_dependencies(simple_marker
> beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
> 
> # %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%
```

I am able to run the basic controls tutorial in rviz, but I did not compile it, just installed the package and ran: rosrun interactive_marker_tutorials basic_controls

Can someone let me know if it is a CMakeLists thing or am I way off.  I have not been able to find a CMakeLists example for an interactive marker node.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107081/how-do-i-solve-undefined-reference-to-interactive_markers/) by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/58061/karen.rod/) on 2020-08-30**:
I have exactly the same error and I could not solve it with these recommendations. Has anyone else had this same error?

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-03-09**:
I have the same error but my CMakelist.txt is so big and complicated that the recommendations do not work at all :(

**Comment by [Turuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/145331/turuu/) on 2023-04-14**:
Yeah, I'm also getting the same error again and again. As a beginner, it is too hard to figure out what is really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears you don´t have the dependency on the interactive_markers package defined in your package. For an example of how to do that, you can look at the [turtlebot_interactive_markers](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_viz/tree/hydro/turtlebot_interactive_markers) package, which is a pretty simple example of a package using interactive_markers in catkin. The relevant parts are in the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2013-12-06**:
Thank you! I had been looking for an example and just couldn't find it. I'll respond when I get a results.

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2013-12-11**:
That did the trick! I was able to update my CMakeLists with the following:

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
pcl_conversions
pcl_ros
roscpp
sensor_msgs
visualization_msgs
interactive_markers
)

I added the   "visualization_msgs" and "interactive_markers" and it worked. Thanks.

**Comment by [tangeni](https://answers.ros.org/users/60902/tangeni/) on 2020-10-13**:
Thanks, @Stefan. This solved my problem too.